# Online stores for unhulled grains in Europe?

Tags: malt

I'd like to buy some unhulled grains, like unhulled barley and unhulled rice for making my own malts.

Unfortunately, the market for these doesn't really seem to be well organized.

Does anyone know of any online distributors for these?

I am in the UK, which means any Europe-based company should do.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try asking the [Maltsters' Association of Great Britain](http://www.ukmalt.com/) if any of their members could supply you with some. Or maybe one of the homebrew suppliers like [The Malt Miller](http://themaltmiller.co.uk/) would be able to suggest where to get some. Failing that, you could try contacting the [Durden Park Beer Circle](http://www.durdenparkbeer.org.uk/), they produce the [Old British Beers and How To Make Them](http://www.durdenparkbeer.org.uk/Publications.htm) booklet, which contains information about roasting your own grains in an attempt to replicate malts of yesteryear.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop some of the British Maltsters a line I am sure they will be happy to help:

http://www.siba.co.uk/directory/supplier-associate-members/maltsters/